# Can I use "into" instead of "to"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

He was quick to adapt himself to the new system.

= He was quick to adapt himself (into) the new system.

Can I use "into" instead of "to"?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to express. There is no problem using *into*. However, using it will change the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely that would improve the sentence, because *adaptation* here is about self-adjustment **to** the system rather than 'getting installed' *into* it.